# How to import user define module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote code in spyder ide and name it as test1.py and wrote another code where i have call 1st code.

1st code:

```
def buildConnectionString(params):
    """Build a connection string from a dictionary of parameters."""
    return ";".join(["%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in params.items()])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myParams = {"server":"mpilgrim", \
                "database":"master", \
                "uid":"sa", \
                "pwd":"secret" \
               }
    print buildConnectionString(myParams)
```

2nd code :

```
import test1

Params = {"server":"mpilgrim", \
            "database":"master", \
            "uid":"sa", \
            "pwd":"secret" \
         }

print test1.buildConnectionString(Params)
```

but im getting an error print buildConnectionString(myParams)
`NameError: name 'myParams' is not defined`.

Comment: fix your indentation please.

Comment: Better yet why don't you just copy that method into the second code's file. Method isn't very big....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation.  My guess is that the code you are running still has one of the indentation issues of the code posted here.

The last line of the imported file

```
print buildConnectionString(myParams)
```

needs to be indented to be in the

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

block.  Otherwise, it is trying to execute upon import when the `myParams` dict has not been defined.

Answer (score 1):

`__name__` won't be `"__main__"` if the file is imported as a module (it will be `"test1"`), so `myParams` is never defined.

Comment: Wrong.  The return statement is before it, so it should work.  The later lines are for testing running the module as standalone.

Comment: @mikeb The error is in the last line of the first code. `myParams` is not defined there when the module is imported.

Comment: @mikeb No, it isn't :-)

Comment: Yes, it is.  If you'll look, the function is defined by the first line.  The second line is the return statement for the function.  You'll notice that the function takes the parameter params, so it is defined before the if.  After the if, if the file is run with `python file.py` it will *test* the function.  If the file is imported, the function will be defined properly.  Python 101

Comment: yes i have added a empty file init.py...And even when i skip if statement get same error.

Comment: @mikeb Wrong, because the last line is outside the `if` scope. So, even when imported, the function will be called but the argument won't be defined.

Answer (score 0):

When you import a python module, you need to have an `__init__.py` file in the directory of the module (it can be empty).

Your indentation looks funky, but I'm assuming that's formatting here.

[See the modules docs for python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: I don't think you need an `__init__.py` file in the directory. For example, if you just define methods in the body of `custoModule.py` file and then `import customModule` in another file in the same directory, when you run the 2nd script python will create a `customModule.pyc` file. No `__init__.py` necessary.

Comment: I don't have an `__init__.py`, empty or otherwise, and my imports work fine, for included modules or ones I wrote myself.

Comment: Indentation is fine as i got correct output for the first code.

Comment: @Ekta - If your indentation is fine in your code, then it doesn't match what you posted, because the code you posted couldn't possibly have worked with that indentation.